# Fetch data from api and set the values for the graph in Material UI and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, charts, material-ui

I have 4 APIs and I need to fetch details and store it on a bar graph according to the name
(Name on x-axis and Details on y-axis, 4 bars for each name):
The API result shows following details:

API 1: Ontime

```
 [
    {
        "Name": "Apoorva",
        "Ontime": 3
    },
    {
        "Name": "Rani",
        "Ontime": 2
    }
]
```

API 2: Pending

```
[
{
    "Name": "Rani",
    "Pending": 4,
},
{
   "Name": "Anshu",
   "Pending" : 3,
}
```

]
API 3: Completed With Delay

```
[
    {
        "Completed with Delay": 1,
        "Name": "Sania"
    }
     {
        "Completed with Delay": 2,
        "Name": "Rani"
    }
    
]
```

API 4 Overdue

```
[
   {
        "Overdue": 1,
        "Name": "Anshu"
    }
]
```

Now in the front-end I had static data, but I want to pass the JSON data returned from the api, can someone please tell how to call the apis and store the data in the graph.

Below is the static code for the same:

```
 const data = {
datasets: [
  {
    backgroundColor: colors.blue[200],
    data: [18, 21, 19, 27, 30],
    label: 'Pending'
  },
  {
    backgroundColor: colors.green[500],
    data: [12, 21, 12, 24, 26 ],
    label: 'Completed On Time'
  },
  {
    backgroundColor: colors.red[300],
    data: [4,3,4,5,6],
    label: 'Overdue'
  },
  {
    backgroundColor: colors.orange[500],
    data: [2,2,1,2,3],
    label: 'Completed with Delay[![enter image description here][1]][1]'
  },
 

],
labels: ['Apoorva', 'Rani', 'Anshu', 'Sania']
```

};

I want the data to be displayed according to the API and display it in the graph.

There is one more API which fetches the names(labels):

```
[
    "Apoorva",
    "Anshu",
    "Rani",
    "Sania",
    "Elle"
]
```

Axios Code:

```
 const [rm, setRm] = useState([]);


const [ontime, setOntime] = useState([]);
  const [pending, setPending] = useState([]);
  const[delay,setDelay] = useState([]);
  const[overdue,setOverdue] = useState([]);
  const rmtlid = `200000`;
  //Fetches the names (labels) - ["Apoorva","Anshu","Rani","Sania","Elle"]
  useEffect(() => {
    RMService.showRMSUnderMe(`${rmtlid}`)
      .then((res => {
        setRm(res.data);
      }))

      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }, []);
  //Fetches the name and the onTime count (API 1)
  useEffect(() => {
    RMService.showOnTime(`${rmtlid}`)
      .then((res => {
        setOntime(res.data);
      }))

      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }, []);
  //Fetches the name and the count of Completed with Delay - API 3
  useEffect(() => {
    RMService.showCompletedwithDelay(`${rmtlid}`)
      .then((res => {
        setDelay(res.data);
      }))

      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }, []);
 ////Fetches the name and the count of Overdue  - API 3
  useEffect(() => {
    RMService.showOverdue(`${rmtlid}`)
      .then((res => {
        setOverdue(res.data);
      }))

      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }, []);
```

Now how do I map the data retrieved from the api(the output given above) with the "data" which will set the graph.

Please help, thanks in advance :)
I am unable to understand how to store the values and display it according to the names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios). Axios is a library to simplify HTTP requests.
You need first of all check the API docs to see how to fetch their data.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.

I can see that the data from the APIs calls you did leave on:
.ontime
.pending
.delay
.overdue

You assign the data you fetched to the variables above respectively.
I'd suggest you to console.log what you got back.
 e.g: console.log(ontime).


 To map arrays you could use "map" or "forEach", they are modern javascript array methods.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer.

I can see that the data from the APIs calls you did leave on:

- `ontime`
- `pending`
- `delay`
- `overdue`

You assigned the data you fetched to the variables above respectively.
I'd suggest you to console.log what you got back.

example:

```
console.log(ontime)
```

To map arrays you could use "map" or "forEach", they are modern javascript array methods.

Here is one example interacting with an array and return a list item for every item in the array:

```
mayArray.map(item => <li>{{ item }}</li>
```

You can check de docs here for map:
[MDN - map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Here for forEach:
[MDN - forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)